# checking out a folder out a LFS tracked subfolder in git

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm merging together a couple or repositories into a monorepo
from repo1, repo2, repo3
to
monorepo\repo1, monorepo\repo2, monorepo\repo3

The issue I'm having is with repo3 that contains LFS tracked objects that I would like to checkout individually.
In the past I would git clone repo3 with the exclude * option and then pull the directories that I wanted one by one.
I'm not able to do something similar in the monorepo scenario.

The strategy I'm using for the rest of the folders in the monorepo (to check them out independently) is: I init a new repo, I add the remote then enable sparse checkout on the target folder/folders and call the checkout.
This does not seem to work on the LFS tracked objects. 
Anyone doing something similar?